Refining scope and new site name
This is part of the second step into an attempted reboot of this community: Rebooting Cognitive Sciences: a Suggested Approach

This site is now several years in beta, and it is about time we revisit and more concretely define which scientific disciplines are in scope, and how this should be reflected in the site name. The discussion on these issues is summarized in the recent community review:

Scope:  Which fields of study can ask questions here? How to deal with overlap with other sites?

We decided to welcome any cognitive science, in line with the definition of
  Wikipedia. This
  includes any field which tackles the mind or its processes (behavior),
  including animals.
  E.g., Human-Computer
  Interaction,
  Neurobiology, Applied
  Psychology, Social
  Psychology,
  Sociology,
  Neuroinformatics.
This implies an overlap with sites like, e.g., Programmers, Biology, UX, Cross Validated, and Skeptics. However, when questions do not
  pertain to the mind or behavior, they are off topic here: e.g. some
  questions about HCI,
  statistics, coding
  experiments.
However, generally we do want to have a scientific focus (whether we accept laymen or not). E.g. the Autism
  proposal was not
  deemed a good fit for this site.
Concrete guidelines for overlap with specific sites is desirable: e.g., Biology, in
  particular neurobiology seems to repeatedly
  overlap.
What to do with questions about highly specific tools and tool requests is still
  undecided. In particular, we have many questions on neuroscience
  software.
There is some discussion on whether or not psychiatry should remain in scope.
Bias-laden questions are off-topic, e.g.,
  improbably human
  conditions.
Our about (help section) of the site should clearly communicate what is in scope and what is
  not.

Site name:  We have noticed our site name might lead to confusion on what this site is, what new name should we use?

The name "Cognitive Sciences" can be interpreted to only welcome cognitive science and cognitive
  psychology, thus
  excluding, e.g., non-cognitive sub-disciplines of psychology. We have
  collected evidence
  showcasing that psychology and neuroscience is often perceived to be
  excluded.
There is a strong majority favoring a name change.
When choosing a new name, the url prefix needs to be considered as well.
Many popular suggestions follow the format "A and B": Cognitive Science and
  Psychology,
  Psychology and
  Neuroscience, Mind
  and Brain.
An attempt at getting an overview of consensus resulted in two favorites (Psychology and Neuroscience, and Mind and
  Brain), with
  Psychology and
  Neuroscience as a
  clear winner.
Unfortunately these suggestions go against the naming standards of SE, which 'suggest'
  avoiding "X and B" like names.
Regardless, this is a topic which keeps resurfacing. The name keeps causing confusion even for active researchers in the
  fields.


The next step now is to collect concrete proposals for a potential different scope and site name, keeping in mind the issues mentioned above. A proposal would do well by including the following:

An exhaustive list of scientific disciplines we want to target explicitly.
A list of scientific disciplines we potentially do not want to consider, including a motivation why.
A suggestion on how to handle overlap with specific other sites.
A suggestion on how to handle questions only tangentially related to the mind, which do not have a home on other sites (given the recent events of the closed neuroscience proposal).
A suggested site name and url prefix, reflecting the earlier described scope, including a motivation.


Let  me add that, although names with ampersands are discouraged, a common name followed by a name with an ampersand might be allowed. We did not yet try pushing for that yet. E.g., my earlier proposal of Cognition: Psychology and Neuroscience.

The Neurobiology issue has been dealt with quite extensively. There is overlap and there always will be was the basic outcome imo. I can dig up the meta posts if you like. Drawing it away from Biology.SE is imho unthinkable as of now.

@Christiaan This is a summary of meta posts I identified. In case you feel this summary leaves out important points which were made over the course of CogSci's existence, you can include missing posts here, and update the summary here.

@StevenJeuris-I've added that meta post. It's a follow up on the previous one by ChuckSherrington/aka Jonsca

@Christiaan, thank you for pointing me to that post I missed. I see you reference several questions there, which we could now consider reopening if we have the necessary community to answer them. Maybe these are questions of interest to those coming in from the closed Neuroscience proposal? This way they can easily obtain the necessary rep to participate on Meta.

Can you check with the moderators about whether "Cognition: Psychology and Neuroscience" is even an option they would accept? Are there previous examples of this form of title in any site?

@Seanny123 Have a look at all the sites: "English Language & Usage", "Music: Practice & Theory". I'm fairly certain they are more likely to accept it as an option than solely the "&" without the prefix. We did ask for solely the "&" combination before.

Hey all. Should measurement (survey, etc.) questions be explicitly included in the scope? I'm thinking of more basic things ("does anyone know of a survey about blah blah blah") and more advanced things (e.g., item construction, validation, even IRT). I also wonder if these have different answers. I did some quick searches and didn't see it mentioned anywhere... Thoughts?

Science
Before starting to list all the bullet points, I want to stress the importance of the word science. That is the beauty of the current site name; it is immediately clear we want to discuss science. Although I actually enjoy the current name, I will suggest a new one at bullet point 5. So, here goes:
The proposal


Neuro-, social-, industry/organizational-, sports-, developmental, behavioral- psychology. The science behind human-factors/HCI, psychiatry, human movements, sociology, linguistics. 
Beside theories and facts, conducting scientific research is also incredibly important. Therefore, methodological questions are also on topic. These methods should be somewhat related to behavior or the brain, including behavioral experimental paradigms and neuroscientific methods.  


Pseudoscience (let's consider this a science for the moment). The reason is clear. 
Topics described in bullet point 1 that are not related to science (e.g. usability issues, parenting tips, psychiatric tips or diagnosis). These are generally self-help questions, opinion based, or clearly belong on another SE-site (e.g. ux, parenting and health, respectively).
Everything other that is not related to behavior or the brain (e.g. physics, philosophy, English language, world building, etc. etc.). 


Biology: Everything that is not related to the brain or behavior should be considered off-topic. This includes (but is not limited to) ecology, genetics, non-animal biology, etc.. All things close to the brain, (networks of) neurons, muscles, sensory systems are on-topic. 
Cross Validated: There are only few statistical methods that are specific for behavioral sciences, and many should thus be migrated, even if they are posed within a behavioral scientific context. Only if the questions are relevant for our site and are conceptual of nature (i.e. not about mathematics or "how- do you calculate") we should welcome them. 
Stack Overflow: I believe there is little overlap here. If they post a line of code in which we must find the incorrect use of a for-loop, then definitely off-topic here. If the question is conceptual and about behavioral sciences (e.g. fieldTrip/EegLAB function) then it will be off-topic at Stack Overflow, and should be on-topic here. 

Each new 'tangentially' related topic should be discussed in a meta post, as is happening now. We cannot decide beforehand what we would accept or not, and we must need acceptance of the current user base. If we see a new Area51 proposal or a trend in new questions that are asked here, we can start the discussion. 
The new name would become Psychological Sciences. I believe it is incredibly important to keep the word science in the name, to clearly show we are about science and not pseudoscience or self-help questions. Psychological, as opposed to Cognitive, should invite more users to come here and will make it easier to find the website. As discussed here as well: (Why is this stack exchange called 'Cognitive Sciences'?), people do not likely search for Cognitive. The url-prefix will become pscience.stackexchange.com. I thought it is a nice play of words and not a cumbersome abbreviation. Alternatively, I would also accept psych.stackexchange.com. 

I do want to express my fear that using the name Psychological Sciences will likely attract many laymen that ask off-topic, self-help and opinionated questions. Psychology is (or sounds) more accessible than Cognition, since the term is better known. If we choose for Psychological Sciences, we have to stay vigilant and close each of these questions without mercy.

I tried to make exhaustive lists of what is on-topic and off-topic, but this was incredibly difficult to me. You cannot name one topic without discussing every other topic (which would make unnecessarily large lists). I hope thus that the proposal is clear. If you need any clarification please say so.

Thank you for a very elaborate description. I'm all +1 on this, except 'psyence' (psych is much better.), and the site name might warrant more discussion, but it is a proposal I did not encounter yet, and I find it intriguing. Would like to hear some counter-arguments against it. I suppose the main one being that it seems only psychology is on-topic.

I unabashedly love this proposal for reasons I will elaborate on soon. Either URL seems good to me.

+1 for everything except "Psychological sciences". This pushes the flavour of the title further away from neuroscience; experimental neuroscience questions should remain on-topic here.

From what I knew during the early stage of [health.se], they fear not slightly misleading site name. My idea was that the site name Medical would attract more academic-level questions than Health, but their stance is that as long as the core members still actively filtering low quality posts, everything still be OK. After a while of inactivity, I see many front-page questions do have this level. That being said, most of them are still lacking adequate research, but that's another story.

I suggest we make a Venn diagram of all the related disciplines, choose one or two biggest circles that cover most areas that we want, then name the site according to that. It will be intuitive, and I think it will clear all the debates. If there is any question about the scope on the site in the future, we just need to re-consider the field again.
For example, this is a discipline diagram for UX:

