Making a CogSci.SE t-shirt
I sometimes attend summer schools and whatnot. A good way to advertise your affiliations in is with a t-shirt. This usually means I end up wearing my Nengo t-shirt, but I'd also like to advertise CogSci.SE.
I'll put some designs up later. But layout wise I'm figuring:

URL on the back
Logo on the front and a slogan under that logo

Potential slogans:

From neuroscience to sociology and everything in between
Researchers helping researchers be more awesome
Get answers, not anecdotes

Design suggestions are appreciated, given my horrible past with t-shirt designs.

You might get reimbursed for this. As far as I know SE supports such endeavors.

Before printing T(hese) shirts, we should determine what our site's name will be: https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2143/11318

I agree! I upvoted your proposed name as hard as I could! I also tried to publicize to the relevant parties, but my social media clout is not as epic as I like to pretend.

@StevenJeuris who would I have to talk to get reimbursed for t-shirts? I feel like I'm getting somewhat close to a final design.

The preferred way seems to be to fill out this contact form, selecting 'I would like to advertise' in the dropdown. I'll have a more thorough look this evening to see whether I can help out.

@StevenJeuris that topic seems to cover printing t-shirt for a give-away at a conference. So I guess I'll follow their instructions once I figure out the next conference I'm going to?

Fourth Draft
I asked a bunch of my graphic design friends what I was doing wrong and their answers were mostly:

Too much text
Too much text of similar weights
Oddly distorted text

So I tried fixing those problems and came up with this, which I'm significantly happier with:

My plan is to make three copies of these somehow and then change the design whenever we change the site name.

Agreed, this is the nicest, although I would drop the thin outline for the disciplines and 'StackExchange'. They always yell 'default cheap photoshop filter' to me. Don't know about others though. :) Would also increase spacing between the brain and 'get answers, not ancedotes' slightly. Possibly to match the spacing between 'StackExchange' and the brain. As is, it is a bit packed. (Wish I still had photoshop, I had a semi-designy past and could have helped you out more than just bashing on the design. :/)

Bringing in gestalt principles, now it seems the 'get answers' text is more related to the brain than it is to 'cognitive sciences'. Evening out this spacing makes everything 'evenly' related you could say. :)

Just to be sure, wasn't sociology considered off-topic?

First Draft
Here's my first draft of the front of the t-shirt. I'll tweak the colours once I decide on a shirt colour. For shirt colours, I'm guessing we should go with white, black or whatever the same light blue of the logo colour.

The InkScape SVG file is available if you want to make further edits and add them as answers to this question. That sound you heard in the distance is all my graphic designer friends screaming in agony.
Things I'm going to try to change:

Giving the fonts an outline
Deciding how I feel about punctuation and where it should be used
Trying to colour the brain
Learning how to center text properly
Making the logo more complex by adding little people on computers on each side


Don't forget to add the url!

Also, i'm not the biggest fan of the font. Would like for something crisper (but wouldn't go as far as serifs). This seems too 'comic' like. You can see, e.g., how the C in 'CgS' has much straighter lines than the C of the surrounding fieldss.

Thanks for the feedback @StevenJeuris! I'm kind of font-blind, so I'll try some alternatives and post the results here. I'm planning on putting the URL on the back of the t-shirt.

Small note, there is Cog Psych twice. Also I think it would be good to state the full name "Cognitive Sciences" once, perhaps in the center above the brain, and move "Cog Neuro" somewhere else (e.g. on the left side). This immediately balances out the amount of tags. Finally, I'm not too sure about the abbreviations. Perhaps we could stick to full names: "Psychology", "Modelling", "Neuroscience", "Sociology", "Cognition", "Psychiatry", "Methodology/Methods". Ps. Sorry for the many critiques, it is easy to criticize for me, less easy to actually make it all up. Thanks for all the effort :)

Your critiques are much appreciated!

Third Draft: t-shirt colour
Which one is better?
White

Black

Or another colour I haven't considered?

I like the white logo better, but I think black shirts would be nicer in reality. So Black +1

isn't the CogSci logo (or stack exchange logo) more square by the way? https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/cogsci/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=f49016372a64

@RobinKramer oops. It might have gotten stretched with all the editing. I'll fix that while I look for a way to make the text on the black t-shirt look a little less weird.

Second Draft
I've decided on the following.

I like punctuation at the ends of sentences
I think Bolded Ubuntu Mono and DejaVu Sans is an okay font
Having "Cognitive Sciences" as a sub-title is helpful
I like short forms over long forms, because balancing long forms was way too hard
Adding anything more to the logo made it seem clutered
I have no idea how to colour the brain and probably shouldn't even try

Front

Back

Attempts at colour

Attempt at long form


I like the improvements! And I understand that you like the short form better this way. Just thinking, in the long form currently, "Neuroscience" and "Cognitive Neuroscience" are both stated. Wouldn't the site name already imply "Cognitive"? What if we'd leave it to just "Neuroscience" (and just "Modelling" and "Psychology")? I don't believe we need too much nuance on a t-shirt.

For me, I think the following seven themes would encapsulate all of CogSci: Psychology, Neuroscience, Sociology, Psychiatry, Modelling and Methodology.

@RobinKramer I like that summary! I'll fix that in the next draft.

For the back, cogsci.stackexchange.com by the way :) Might come in handy for them to know where to find us

What if there's some Quora or ResearchGate guys on the conferences?

@Ooker I'll fight them. With words.

you will hack each other' minds. What a game! // On a serious though, if those sites are bad, then I don't understand why there are still active users on them

@Ooker they're not bad they're just bad at getting professionals to answer another professionals question, as well as curating quality content. It's a complicated problem. We can talk more about this in chat if you'd like.
